# Script to parse weather

Tags: python, python-2.5

I'm trying to learn Python. My only experience is Applescripting and it's not so easy to learn.. so far anyway.

I'm trying to parse an xml weather site and so far I have the data I need but I can't figure out how to get it into a list to process it further. Can anyone help?

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.cElementTree import parse
import urllib2

url = "http://www.weatheroffice.gc.ca/rss/city/ab-52_e.xml"
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
local_file = open("\Temp\weather.xml", "w")
local_file.write(response.read())
local_file.close()

invalid_tags = ['b', 'br'] 

tree = parse("\Temp\weather.xml")

stuff = tree.findall("channel/item/description")

item = stuff[1]

parsewx = BeautifulSoup(stuff[1].text)

for tag in invalid_tags: 
for match in parsewx.findAll(tag): 
    match.replaceWithChildren()

print parsewx
```

Comment: General suggestions: it's usually better to use the [`tempfile module`](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html) to handle temporary files, because it'll avoid conflicts and delete them when it's done and so on. Also, you should use `"\\Temp\\weather.xml"` or `r"\Temp\weather.xml"`, because otherwise it tries to treat those backslashed characters as escape codes; you lucked out that `\T` and `\w` aren't valid escapes and so it works, but if you tried `\t` or `\n` it'd break in surprising ways. If you use [lxml](http://lxml.de/), it'll handle all this for you; you can just `parse` a URL.

Comment: There's an indentation problem in the last two for loops...

Answer (score 0):

Since XML is structured data, BeautifulSoup returns a [tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_structure) of Tags. 
The [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) has extensive information on how to [search](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-the-tree) and [navigate](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigating-the-tree) in that tree.